# ws outbound gateway unmarshaller

Tags: spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration  flow with a WS out bound gateway (with marshaller and unmarshaller). After that i have a transformer.

and when i take the payload in the transformer class using getPayload() method i am getting an object of javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement.
Here I am expecting to get the object of ResponseType class ( generated using jaxb2 plugin), that is what unmarshaller supposed to do..

Whay am i not getting object of type ResponseType in the payload ?

Request your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JAXBElement<ResponseType> resp= (JAXBElement<ResponseType>)payload;
ResponseType response = resp.getValue();
```